# Induced map on stalks of presheaves is equal to induced map on the stalks of the sheafifcation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $f:F\rightarrow G$ be a morphism of presheaves, then there is a unique induced map of $f^+:F^+\rightarrow G^+$, where $F^+$ and $G^+$ are the sheafification of the sheaves. This follows because if $\theta$ is the sheafification morphism, there is a map $\theta\circ f:F\rightarrow G^+$, so by the universal property of sheafification we have a unique map $f^+:F^+\rightarrow G^+$ satisfying $f^+\circ \theta=\theta\circ f$.

Now, by the universal property of the direct limit, there exists a map $f^+_q:F^+_q\rightarrow G^+_q$ such that $f^+_q\circ \theta_q=\theta_q\circ f_q$. I can show that for any presheave $\theta_q$ is an isomorphism, however, the problem I am working on claims that $(f^+)_q=f_q$, and to me this seems to only be true if $\theta_q=\text{Id}$, however this makes no sense to me.

I get there is an isomorphism $F^+_q\cong F_q$, however, this isomorphism does not seem to be the identity. Indeed, the isomorphism is given by sending $s_q\in F_q$ to $(s_p)_q$ where $s$ is any section of $F(U)$, $U$ any open, such that the equivalence class $[U,s]$ is equal to $s_q$, and $(s_p)$ is the image of this section under the map $F(U)\rightarrow F(U)^+$. This is clearly well defined, and it is easy to see it is a bijection, and thus an isomorphism of the underlying rings, but how is it the identity, when the stalks aren't as sets on the nose the same?

Comment: You're right, usually people do mean that the sheafification induces isomorphisms of stalks and identifies the stalks via those isomorphisms. E.g., even https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/007X acknowledge that there is something to prove here even though it looks obvious (Lemma 6.17.2), yet claim equality and prove only that the canonical map is a bijection.

Comment: The isomorphism is natural, btw.

Comment: @Ben so then how do I show that $(f^+)_q$ is the same map as $f_q$?  Or does equality mean something different here?

Comment: The equality is a bit loose. The point is that you have an isomorphism $\theta_q:F_q\to F_q^+$ and an isomorphism $\phi_q:G_q\to G_q^+$. You also have maps $f_q:F_q\to G_q$ and $f_q^+:F_q^+\to G_q^+$. And $f_q$ equals $f_q^+$ in the sense that they commute with the isomorphisms, i.e., $f^+_q\circ \theta_q=\phi_q\circ f_q$. But since the isomorphisms $\theta_q$ and $\phi_q$ are canonical, we like to just say that sheafification doesn’t change the stalks, without worrying about the technicality that the sets aren’t literally the same.

Comment: In a similar vein, I think most people would be OK with writing $F^+=F$ for any sheaf $F$, even though they are not literally the same sheaf. If one is too pedantic when working with sheaves then notation will often become incomprehensibly messy because there’s just too many things to keep track of.

Comment: @KenanskiBowspleefi except in that case they are actually the same by the universal property of sheafification. You have that $(F,\text{Id})$ satisfies the universal property of sheafification so the sheafifiction map is the identity no?

Comment: The universal property only specifies the sheafification up to unique isomorphism. The usual construction of sheafification is the sheaf of compatible sections—this is the construction you seem to be using in the original question—and this is definitely not equal to the original sheaf. But it is isomorphic to it (via a unique isomorphism). This is why you basically have to stop caring about literal equality when working with objects characterized by universal properties.

Comment: @KenanskiBowspleefi Oh ok, so since $(F,\text{Id})$ satisfies the universal property then we just know that it is uniquely isomorphic to $F^+$. I am ok with not carrying about literal equality, I would just like it spelled out what "equality" actually means. Like if two maps are equal if there are unique maps such that $\phi\circ f=f^\circ \psi$ thats fine, I just want to know what definition of "equality" we are using...

Comment: Yeah, I’d say that’s a fair description. We get isomorphisms between the stalks of $F$ and the stalks of the sheafification (and likewise for $G$), and we just pretend they’re the same set via this isomorphism.